# How to search multiple lines of words to the body of email?

Tags: c#, regex, exchangewebservices

how to search multiple lines of words to an email body like

`Remote Server returned '550 No Such User Here'`, `Remote Server returned '554 5.4.4 SMTPSEND.DNS.NonExistentDomain; nonexistent domain'`, or `Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts`. Here is my code to display the body of the undelivered or bounce back emails:

```
private static void DisplayBody(ExchangeService service)
{
        PropertySet itemProperty = new PropertySet();
        itemProperty.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
        itemProperty.Add(ItemSchema.Body);
        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.DR"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.DELAYED"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.IPNRN"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.IPNNRN"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.SMIME.NDR"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.SMIME.DR"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.NoteSMIME.MULTIPARTSIGNED.NDR"));
        searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.SMIME.MULTIPARTSIGNED.DR"));
        PropertySet FindItemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

        ItemView view = new ItemView(999);
        view.PropertySet = FindItemPropertySet;
        PropertySet GetItemsPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        GetItemsPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = null;

        do
        {
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);
            if (findResults.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, GetItemsPropertySet);
                foreach (Item Item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    string EmailHeader = Item.Body.Text;
                    Console.WriteLine(Item.Body.Text);
                }
            }
        } while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
}
```

can anyone help me or give me a hint on how to search on the body of an email thanks in advance and Happy New Year

Comment: I have no idea what "how to search multiple lines of words to an email body?" means. Can you clarify?

Comment: im sorry im super sleepy, i mean i want to search a line llike "Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts" on the body of an email. on my program i display the email and i want to search now a line of words.

Comment: Use a regex like `(?s)(?<=EMAIL_BODY_START).*?(?=EMAIL_BODY_END)`

Comment: ok thanks for the information

Comment: Why do you assign `Item.Body.Text` to a variable named `EmailHeader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume your phrases are not broken up across lines, you can just look for them:

```
var EmailBody = Item.Body.Text;
var messages = new[] {
    "Remote Server returned '550 No Such User Here'",
    "Remote Server returned '554 5.4.4 SMTPSEND.DNS.NonExistentDomain; nonexistent domain'",
    "Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts." };

var found = messages.Any(m => EmailBody.Contains(m));
```

If it is possible they might be broken up, you can use `Regex` and handle all whitespace:

```
var EmailBody = Item.Body.Text;
var messages = (new[] {
    "Remote Server returned '550 No Such User Here'",
    "Remote Server returned '554 5.4.4 SMTPSEND.DNS.NonExistentDomain; nonexistent domain'",
    "Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts." })
    .Select(m => Regex.Escape(m).Replace(@"\ ",@"\s+"))
    .ToArray();


var found = messages.Any(m => Regex.IsMatch(EmailBody, m));
```

If they can be broken across lines in the middle of words, it is a bit harder, but I assume that is unlikely.

To return the matching message(s), you can do something like this:

```
var foundMessages = messages.Where(m => EmailBody.Contains(m)).ToList();
```

Then `foundMessages.Count` will tell you if any were found.

Comment: i tried to run the result on the console and it showing the result true. how to display the line that i've search thanks

Comment: I added an example of remembering the match.